# Blueprint library's DateRangePicker, provides no way to control the value shown in the TimePicker Component, when not in singleMonthOnly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, daterangepicker, blueprintjs

1. In my React App i am using `DateRangePicker` from BluePrint Library [DOCS, ik it's depreciated](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#datetime/daterangepicker)
2. I have set the `singleMonthOnly` prop to false, hence i can see 2 months current & previous month
3. I have set the `timePickerProps` precision to `seconds`, which enables the timePicker Component beneath the Calendar's
4. Because i have two calendar's displayed i also have two timePicker compoents displayed

**Code for reference**

```js
<DateRangePicker
    className={Classes.ELEVATION_1}
    onChange={handleChange}
    allowSingleDayRange={true}
    singleMonthOnly={false}
    contiguousCalendarMonths={false}
    shortcuts={false}
    timePickerProps={{
        precision: 'second',
        selectAllOnFocus: true,
        value: new Date(),// <==================== Code Reference Point 1
        onChange: function (newTime) {
            console.log("Hello", newTime)// <<========= Code Reference Point 2
        }
    }}
    maxDate={new Date()}
    highlightCurrentDay
    defaultValue={[
        timeRangeParam && urlTimeRange && urlTimeRange.length > 0
            ? new Date(parseInt(urlTimeRange[0]))
            : null,
        timeRangeParam && urlTimeRange && urlTimeRange.length > 0
            ? new Date(parseInt(urlTimeRange[1]))
            : null,
    ]}
    value={dateRangePickerValue} // <================ Code Reference Point 3
/>
```

**UI for reference**
[image]

❌**Issue**❌

When i change the value of the first timePicker the onChange is called and i can see the console.log(*Code Reference Point 2*) for hello as in code above and when i change the value of the second one i can see the same console.log for hello.

Also the value that is expected is a single Date Object(*Code Reference Point 1*) but it should be an Array like such [Date, Date] so that one can control the two timePickers Individually.

Thank Fully the interface for the value(Code Reference Point 3) taken by the parent DateRangePicker is a [Date, Date] range.[DatePicker Interface](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/61a88675e/packages/datetime/src/common/dateRange.ts#L17)

❓**Main Question**❓
How am i supposed to take control of the 2 timePicker Individually ?
If i cannot access the  onChange separately, how am i supposed to know which one to change ?